# Glyphicon for ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to use Glyphicon for my React Project. I followed this site https://www.golangprograms.com/reactjs-an-example-glyphicon-rating-star-component.html
for reference. It did not work. So I checked my react-bootstrap file in node_modules, there was no Glyphicon.

How can I import Glyphicon other than doing

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Reference the [bootstrap icon page](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/) and copy the raw SVG element:

```
<svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-star-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.283.95l-3.523 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z"/>
</svg>
```

2. Import and reference like so:

```
npm install bootstrap-icons
```

```
<svg class="bi" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor">
  <use xlink:href="bootstrap-icons.svg#star-fill"/>
</svg>
```